# How we safe Battery life of Iphone 13 Pro?

Tags: mobile

How we safe Battery life of Iphone 13 Pro?

To help maximize the battery life of your iPhone 13 Pro, you can follow these tips:

1. Optimize screen brightness: Lower the screen brightness or enable auto-brightness to conserve battery power.
2. Enable Low Power Mode: Activate the Low Power Mode feature, which reduces background activity and adjusts settings to extend battery life.
3. Manage app background activity: Limit or disable background app refresh for unnecessary apps. This prevents them from consuming battery power when not in use.
4. Control push email and fetch settings: Adjust email settings to fetch new messages less frequently or manually, reducing the frequency of data updates and conserving battery life.
5. Use Wi-Fi instead of cellular data: When possible, connect to Wi-Fi networks as they consume less power compared to cellular data.
6. Limit location services: Review and restrict the apps that have access to your location data, as constant GPS usage can drain the battery. Choose "While Using" or "Ask Next Time" for location access.
7. Disable unnecessary notifications: Minimize the number of app notifications you receive, as they can activate the display and consume battery power.
8. Close unused apps: Close apps running in the background that you're not actively using. This prevents them from consuming system resources and draining the battery.
9. Update to the latest iOS version: Keep your iPhone's software up to date to ensure you have the latest battery optimization enhancements and bug fixes.
10. Use optimized charging: Enable the "Optimized Battery Charging" feature, which learns your daily charging patterns and helps slow down battery aging by reducing the time your iPhone spends fully charged.

Implementing these practices providing by [currentpackages](https://currentpackages.com/) should help extend the battery life of your iPhone 13 Pro and ensure optimal usage throughout the day.

Please give your personal opinions for betterment.